# Display multiple Trending Topics at the same time in TweetDeck

Tags: twitter, tweetdeck

I want to display multiple trending topics at the same time in TweetDeck. For example, I want to view Worldwide, Turkey and United States side by side. I'm selecting `Add Column > Core` and `Trending Topics`, but it doesn't add more than 1 TT column. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: NO,TweetDeck does not support that. Try [twimbow](http://www.twimbow.com)

Answer (score -1):

I've created a Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey script for this. http://www.willhawker.com/sandbox/add-a-trends-column-to-tweetdeck